# How to get SDK Version inside of a class?

Tags: android

How do you get the sdk version inside a class? I want to compare the SDK version to a number and do something if its a certain verion.

Comment: Have a look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551959/possible-to-only-load-specific-lines-of-code-according-to-android-os-version/3552129#3552129

Comment: Seems to be answered here:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882883/retrieve-android-sdk-version/1883201#1883201>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) to get an int representing the SDK version, and compare it to a given [version code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) : `Build.VERSION_CODES.*` (`ECLAIR`, `FROYO`, etc...).

This is available from anywhere in your code, and works starting at API Level 4. Prior to API Level 4 (if you plan on targeting really old devices), you can use `Build.VERSION_SDK`, which returns pretty much the same information but in a String (then use Integer.parseInt to parse it...).

Answer (score 0):

`Build.VERSION.RELEASE` can give you the user-visible version string (i.e 1.5, 1.6, 2.0), while `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` can give you a value from `Build.VERSION_CODES` that would be better to use if you want to compare against it (programatically).

But `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is only available on Android 1.6 and newer. Build.VERSION.SDK will work on all Android releases, including 1.5. However, once you elect to drop 1.5 support, switching to `SDK_INT` is a good idea.